# Does secondary or backup MX server deliver queued emails to users?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, imap, pop3

Suppose, I have a primary MX: mx1.abc.com with priority 5 and secondary mx as mx2.abc.com with Priority 10. I have independent IMAP/POP servers configured to fetch email for abc.com domain. (imap.abc.com & pop3.abc.com)

Suppose mx1.abc.com goes down, is it possible for mx2.abc.com to deliver emails to imap/pop3.abc.com and finally to users of abc.com ?

As per my understanding, secondary MX just holds the queue and forward those emails to primary mail server as soon as it gets up.

Is it really possible ?

Please clear my confusions with technical ideas. I'd love to get answers on or at least receive some hints. :-)

Comment: I don't think you're asking about the American Broadcasting Company's mail infrastructure, so please don't use their domain names. Use your own domain or refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions.

Comment: What happens depends on how you configure your server(s) and how you design your infrastructure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done on  your email servers themselves and dns records help with the routing of incoming email and thats it. Dependig on which mail server your actually using will decide on how difficult the task your trying to accomplish will be. But you can setup your primary server to start pushing emails to que in your secondary server. Then you can either setup your secondary to send the emails itself or to periodically check the first server and feed the emails to it as the que empties and have the first server send them. Just make sure you setup basic spf records for both servers if both servers are sending the emails, if the first server is going to send the mail only you only need to setup an spf record for the first server.